# bbcode ckeditor justify plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor, bbcode

i install ckeditor and after i install that code (bbcode plugin):

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/bbcode/plugin.js

and i install that code (justify plugin):

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/justify/plugin.js

and after i install that plugins all work but when i click center or right or left in the justify plugin - the bbcode plugin not support the justify mod.

anybody can help me build a simple code in the bbcode plugin support the justify mod?

its for forum and i need only bbcode.

i need code like :

if  `<span style=\"text-align: center;\">texthere</span>`

its replace to `[center]texthere[/center]`

or something like that.

thx for the help.

i try this code:

```
(function() {
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('bbcode',
  {
    requires: ['htmlwriter'],
    init: function(editor) {
      editor.dataProcessor = new CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor(editor);
      editor.dataProcessor.toHtml = toHtml;
      editor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat = toDataFormat;
    }
  });

  var toHtml = function(data, fixForBody) {
    // Convert < and > to their HTML entities.
    data = data.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    data = data.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

    // Convert line breaks to <br>.
    data = data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '<br>');

    // [url]
    data = data.replace(/\[url\](.+?)\[\/url]/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
    data = data.replace(/\[url\=([^\]]+)](.+?)\[\/url]/gi, '<a href="$1">$2</a>');


    // [b]
    data = data.replace(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b]/gi, '<b>$1</b>');

    // [i]
    data = data.replace(/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i]/gi, '<i>$1</i>');

    // [u]
    data = data.replace(/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u]/gi, '<u>$1</u>');

    // [h3]
    data = data.replace(/\[h3\](.*?)\[\/h3](?:<br ?\/?>|\n)?/gi, '<h3>$1</h3>');

    // [img]
    data = data.replace(/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/gi,'<img src="$1" />');
    data = data.replace(/\[img class=([\w-]+)\](.*?)\[\/img\]/gi,'<img class="$1" src="$2" />');

    // [quote]
    data = data.replace(/\[quote\]/gi, '<blockquote>');
    data = data.replace(/\[\/quote]/gi, '</blockquote>');

    // [poster]
    data = data.replace(/\[poster\](.+?)\[\/poster]/gi, '<div class="text-poster">$1</div>');

    // [code]
    data = data.replace(/\[code\]/gi,'<code>');
    data = data.replace(/\[\/code\]/gi,'</code>');

    // [size]
    data = data.replace(/\[size=(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/size\]/gi,'<span style="font-size: $1px">$2</span>');

    // [color]
    data = data.replace(/\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/gi,'<span style="color: $1">$2</span>');

    // [center] 
    data = data.replace(/\[align=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/align\]/gi,'<span style="align: center">$2</span>');

    // [right] 
    data = data.replace(/\[align=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/align\]/gi,'<span style="align: right">$2</span>');

    // [left] 
    data = data.replace(/\[align=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/align\]/gi,'<span style="align: left">$2</span>');


    // smileys
    for (var i = 0; i < this.editor.config.smiley_images.length; i++) {
      var smiley = this.editor.config.smiley_images[i].replace('.gif', '');
      if (data.indexOf(smiley) != -1) {
        data = data.split(smiley).join('<img src="'+ this.editor.config.smiley_path + this.editor.config.smiley_images[i] + '" class="smiley" />');
      }
    }

    return data;
  };
  var toDataFormat = function(html, fixForBody ) {
    if (html == '<br>' || html == '<p><br></p>') {
      return "";
    }
    // Convert <br> to line breaks.
    html = html.replace(/<br><\/p>/gi,"\n");
    html = html.replace(/<br(?=[ \/>]).*?>/gi, '\r\n');
    html = html.replace(/<p>/gi,"");
    html = html.replace(/<\/p>/gi,"\n");
    html = html.replace(/&nbsp;/gi," ");

    // [url]
    html = html.replace(/<a .*?href=(["'])(.+?)\1.*?>(.+?)<\/a>/gi, '[url=$2]$3[/url]');

    // [b]
    html = html.replace(/<(?:b|strong)>/gi, '[b]');
    html = html.replace(/<\/(?:b|strong)>/gi, '[/b]');

    // [i]
    html = html.replace(/<(?:i|em)>/gi, '[i]');
    html = html.replace(/<\/(?:i|em)>/gi, '[/i]');

    // [u]
    html = html.replace(/<u>/gi, '[u]');
    html = html.replace(/<\/u>/gi, '[/u]');

    // [h3]
    html = html.replace(/<h3>/gi, '[h3]');
    html = html.replace(/<\/h3>/gi, '[/h3]\n');

    // smileys
    html = html.replace(/<img .*?src=(["']).+?(:.+?:?|(\W)_\3).gif\1.*?>/gi, '$2');

    // [img]
    html = html.replace(/<img .*?class=(["'])([\w-]+)\1.*?src=(["'])(.+?)\3.*?>/gi, '[img class=$2]$4[/img]');
    html = html.replace(/<img .*?src=(["'])(.+?)\1.*?class=(["'])([\w-]+)\3.*?>/gi, '[img class=$4]$2[/img]');
    html = html.replace(/<img .*?src=(["'])(.+?)\1.*?>/gi, '[img]$2[/img]');

    // [quote]
    html = html.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '[quote]');
    html = html.replace(/\n*<\/blockquote>/gi, '[/quote]');

    // [poster]
    html = html.replace(/<div class="text-poster">([\s\S]+?)<\/div>/gi, '[poster]$1[/poster]');

    // [code]
    html = html.replace(/<code>/gi, '[code]');
    html = html.replace(/<\/code>/gi, '[/code]');

    // [color]
    html = html.replace(/<span style="color: ?(.*?);?">(.*?)<\/span>/gi,"[color=$1]$2[/color]");

    // [size]
    html = html.replace(/<span style="font-size: ?(\d+)px;?">(.*?)<\/span>/gi,"[size=$1]$2[/size]");

    // Remove remaining tags.
    html = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');

    // Restore < and >
    html = html.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    html = html.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');

    // Restore (and )
    html = html.replace(/%28/g, '(');
    html = html.replace(/%29/g, ')');

    // Restore %20
    html = html.replace(/%20/g, ' ');

    return html;
  }
})();
```

but this code not work.

i think this code for ckeditor 3 or something ..

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem today and I managed to make it work by modifying the *plugin.js* in the bbcode plugin folder

Line 29：

```
var bbcodeMap = { b: 'strong', u: 'u', i: 'em', color: 'span', size: 'span', quote: 'blockquote', code: 'code', url: 'a', email: 'span', img: 'span', '*': 'li', list: 'ol',center:'div',left:'div',right:'div'},
```

and Line around 151-160：

```
// as "span" with an attribute marker.
if ( part == 'email' || part == 'img' )
attribs[ 'bbcode' ] = part;

//adding this to deal with the align issues
if (part == 'center' || part == 'left' || part == 'right'){
styles ['text-align'] = part;
attribs.style = serializeStyleText( styles );
}

this.onTagOpen( tagName, attribs, CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty[ tagName ] );
```

And finally line start from 658:

```
if ( tagName in convertMap )
    tagName = convertMap[ tagName ];
//adding div element
else if (tagName == 'div'){
    if ( ( value = style['text-align'] ) ) {
        tagName = value;
        value = '';
    }
}
else if ( tagName == 'span' ) {
if ( ( value = style.color ) ) {
    tagName = 'color';
    value = CKEDITOR.tools.convertRgbToHex( value );
....
```

At least this works for me.

This is kind of weired because the Justify Plugin is adding 'div' elements instead of 'span'. Maybe you can also modify it to satisfy your 'span' requirement.